# How to I parse a file and only keep certain words?

Tags: command-line, grep

Let's say I have a list of words I want to keep.

```
list=['hi','name','first']
```

I want to be able to go through a text file, keep each and every word in my list, and output the new cleaned up content to a new file.
For example:

have:

```
hi my name is Mike. Please write your name here first and then sign there.
```

want:

```
hi name name first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the words in a separate file, one per line, you can use `grep`:

```
grep -oFf word-list.txt input-file
```

- `-o` prints only matching strings
- `-F` treats the patterns as fixed strings instead of regular expressions
- `-f file` reads in patterns from a file.

With python:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
words=['hi','name','first']
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(' '.join(filter(lambda x: x in words, line.split())))
```

Comment: The grep version of the answer does not work: substrings match (for example first will match if firstname is in the file being searched).
I am not overly versed in Python, but this seems to do it right, I would have offered a similar solution with awk.

Comment: @asoundmove use `-w`, then.

Comment: Sure, I did forget that one.

Comment: or shorter: `print((" ").join([w for w in open("/file").read().split() if w in l]))` (where `l=['hi','name','first']` without importing sys)